# Can't figure out what's wrong in my switch syntax

Tags: c, switch-statement, syntax-error

Ok guys, I'm having trouble with my switch syntax and I don't know why I can't compile it.

I'm posting the part of the code that's wrong so you can help me.

If you need any information about the code, just ask me.

```
for (c=0; c<3; c++) // 3 jogadores ( 4 - voce )
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 0:
            char cartas[7];
            cartas[0] = jog2_carta1[0];
            cartas[1] = jog2_carta1[1];
            cartas[2] = jog2_carta2[0];
            cartas[3] = jog2_carta2[1];
            cartas[4] = jog2_carta3[0];
            cartas[5] = jog2_carta3[1];
            cartas[6] = '\0';

            if (strcmp(retornaMaior(cartas,mesa_jog1[0]), "00") == 1)
            {
               printf("%s", retornaMaior(cartas,mesa_jog1[0]));
               maiorRodada = 2;
               // remove carta (na funcao)
            }
            else
            {
                // remove menor
            }
            break;
        case 1: // jogador 3
            char cartas[7];
            cartas[0] = jog3_carta1[0];
            cartas[1] = jog3_carta1[1];
            cartas[2] = jog3_carta2[0];
            cartas[3] = jog3_carta2[1];
            cartas[4] = jog3_carta3[0];
            cartas[5] = jog3_carta3[1];
            cartas[6] = '\0';

            if (strcmp(retornaMaior(cartas,mesa_jog2[0]), "00") == 1)
            {
                if (maiorRodada == 2)
                {
                    printf("%s", retornaMaior(cartas,mesa_jog2[0]));
                    maiorRodada = 3;
                    // remove carta (na funcao)
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                // remove menor
            }
            break;
        case 2: // jogador 4
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactlty is the compiler error?

Comment: The compiler does not like 'in between' definition of new variables. Move them somewhere out of this switch (best practice) or "hide" them by putting curly braces around the entire inner part of each `case` (not so good practice, but hey! it works).

Comment: @Jongware: As of C99, it's legal to mix declarations and statements. The problem is that a case label (or other label) can't be applied to a declaration.

Comment: Presumably the error is the declaration of `char cartas[7];` happening twice within the switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you're asking about a syntax error, always show us the exact error message, and clearly indicate which line it refers to.

The problem is that the syntax for a statement with a case label is:

`case` *constant-expression* `:` *statement*

You have:

```
case 0:
    char cartas[7];
    cartas[0] = jog2_carta1[0];
    // ...
```

`char cartas[7];` is a *declaration*, not a *statement*.

You can solve this by enclosing the body of each `case` with curly braces, making the entire block of code (including the leading declarations) a single statement:

```
case 0:
    {
        char cartas[7];
        cartas[0] = jog2_carta1[0];
        // ...
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You might like to open a fresh context for each `case` statement, like this:

```
switch(c)
{
  case 0:
  {
     /* Put variable definitons here. */
  }
  case 1:
  {
  }
  ...
  default:
  {
  }
}
```